# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{3^n\ \sin(n)}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Does this series converge? Root test and ratio test are inconclusive.

Comment: Related question : http://mathoverflow.net/questions/24579/convergence-of-sumn3-sin2n-1

Comment: @hallaplay835, yes it exists, check this link to be sure of it : http://math.stackexchange.com/a/736374/140057

Comment: This is an exercise in an introduction to series text. There's no way this was supposed to be solved using irrationality measure of $\pi$.

Comment: @hallaplay835 can you list the theorems you know about series ?

Answer (score 3):

Using the same arguments as in the two answers of [Does $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n! \sin(n)}$ diverge or converge?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/736361/does-sum-n-1-infty-frac1n-sinn-diverge-or-converge/736374#736374) we can compare the series $\sum^\infty_{n=1}\left|\frac{1}{3^n\sin n}\right|$ to $\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{n^7}{3^n}$, which certainly converges by the ratio test, so that the original series converges (absolutely).